# Markov Chain Find E[X1|X0 = 2] and Find P(X1 =3, X2=1|X0=2)

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-probability

So I've looked through my book for hours and maybe I'm not googling the right thing but I'm not sure what part b for each of these problems is asking me to do. Can anyone tell me what it means? I know for 4.1.2 it's asking for the probability but I'm not sure of what or in what order.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P\equiv(p_{i,j})$ be the transition matrix associated with this time-homogeneous Markov chain.
That is,
$$
p_{i,j}\equiv\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=j\mid X_{n}=i).
$$
For the first question, apply the definition of expectation:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}\mid X_{0}=2\right]=\sum_{x}p_{2,x}\cdot x.
$$
For the second question, use the Markov property:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=3,X_{2}=1\mid X_{0}=2)=\mathbb{P}(X_{1}=3\mid X_{0}=2)\mathbb{P}(X_{2}=1\mid X_{1}=3)=p_{2,3}p_{3,1}.
$$